# Groovy slow to load on first call from Java

Tags: java, groovy, classloader

I am using Groovy to do some calculations, within an RCP app. When I first click the button that calls the Groovy code, I get a bit of a delay, which doesn't exist on the next and subsequent clicks. Is there any way I can warm the cache (so to speak) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's calling the groovy code the first time that slows you down, can't you call the groovy code sometime earlier? Maybe even spin off another thread just to call it?